# how to disable restricted mode feature &/or banner in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever, I open vscode, it says (in a banner on top):

> Restricted Mode is intended for safe code browsing. Trust this window
> to enable all features. Manage Learn More

Screenshot attached bellow:

[image]

I do not need both this feature &/or banner.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust#_settings) might help you disable `workspace trust`.

You'll probably need to set `security.workspace.trust.enabled` as `false` in your settings.

Other than that, there is also a command-line switch ( `--disable-workspace-trust`) which you can pass while opening vscode which will disable this feature

Answer (score 7):

`File > Preferences > Settings >` Search for `"Trust"` and then disable the checkbox that says

> "Controls whether or not workspace trust is enabled within VS Code."

Then after the restart you're good to go.