# Vscode autocomplete not working in javascript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I would like to know if anyone knows how to fix autocompletion in vscode. This is my problem: vscode has a code suggestion, but lately it stopped working in my javascript file I leave a picture of how it doesn't work.

[image: code to show autocomplete not working]

On line 31 it should suggest "addEventListener" but it doesn't, does anyone know why?

I already checked that the factory application "typescrit and javascrit language features" was active. Also the file is in JS format. I also reloaded the editor with ctrl + shift + p -> developer: reload window.

From already thank you very much.

Comment: When i code previous the autocomplete it worked, but not now. If that was the case i would not be posting this issue.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my VSC ..? Is the file you're working with really a .js file, and you're not writing inline script to a html file?

Comment: Yes, really is a .js file, i not using inline script tag inside html file.

Answer (score 2):

You are in restricted mode which is a security feature to protect your machine from malicious repositories. A better approach to outright disabling the feature is to trust whatever folder you normally clone your own repositories in. When you initially open a new folder you are presented with this dialog:

[image]

You can say yes here to get the functionality working, there's also a checkbox that allows you to trust the parent folder of the folder you opened as it's a common pattern to clone all your repositories in a single folder.

If you need to fine tune which folder you trust you can open "Manage Workspace Trust" from the gear menu:

[image]

On this page you can trust the folder you clone your own repositories into, or alternatively the whole drive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just now i learn how to fixed: is the restricted mode. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948822/how-to-disable-restricted-mode-feature-or-banner-in-vscode?fbclid=IwAR3PuCeGGwvGoptsqa1-uezJ3RvRCY7iSwu3k5GsqxRGCtlXIiStvelAU2o) to know how to fixed.

In summary:

1. Open settings (ctrl+,)
2. Write in the nav bar: "security.workspace.trust.enabled"
3. Disable the check box (turn to false)
4. Done.